# Where do AWS lamba's load credentials from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am writing an AWS Lamda in C# using this example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-creating-project-in-visual-studio.html

I have set my credentials in the environmental variables according to this document:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

But when I try to upload my lamda I get errors about not having the correct IAM roles.  However, the account name in the error message is not the same as the account I put into the credentials in the environmental variables.  It relates to an account on a different S3 bucket which I was testing with little while ago.

Where is it reading this from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have set my credentials in the environmental variables according to this document

This is **not a good practice**. The lambda permissions  should be provided using [lambda execution role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html). Once you set the role, AWS SDK will automatically get the **temporary** credentials from your function's  [runtime environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime).

Since it seems that you need a **cross-account access** in your function, then you have to use cross-account roles as explained in AWS docs:

- [How do I configure a Lambda function to assume an IAM role in another AWS account?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/)

Comment: Thanks.  I am confused though, I only need access to one account for this function.  The previous test account is not relevant to these tests.  The lamda execution role seems to be designed for functions that are already uploaded, how do I upload the function I wrote?

Comment: @Stefan I would setup aws config files as shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html). Using them, you don't need to fiddle with your env variables on your local machine.

Comment: I have created the UserProfile env variable and a .aws directory, a credentials file with the relevant credentials but the AWS Upload is still giving an error with the wrong credentials.  :-(  I do not see where it could read them from.

Comment: @Stefan Check [precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html#cli-configure-quickstart-precedence) of credentials, and see what could be the one that gives you the wrong ones.

Comment: aha!  There was another copy of the files which had the wrong credentials in!  I thought the env variables took priority but apparently they don't.  Thanks! :-)